# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'gameHallID' cannot be null in Symfony One to Many Relationship

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have two tables store and store_timings in which i would like to save store timings from mon to sun.I have created two entities Store.php and Store_timings.php

> Store.php

```
namespace Test\BotBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Store
*
* @ORM\Table(name="store", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idxReference", 
columns={"reference"}), @ORM\Index(name="idxLounges", columns={"name", 
"province", "loungePage"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Store
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="storeID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $storeID;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="openinghours", type="blob", length=65535, nullable=true)
 */
private $openinghours;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="document", type="blob", length=65535, nullable=true)
 */
private $document;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings",mappedBy="gameHallOpeningHours",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $gameHallOpeningHours;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="addedTs", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $addedts;

/**
 * Store constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->gameHallOpeningHours = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getStoreId()
{
    return $this->storeID;
}

/**
 * @param Store $storeId
 */
public function setStoreId(Store $storeId)
{
    $this->storeId = $storeId;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @param string $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getOpeninghours()
{
    return $this->openinghours;
}

/**
 * @param string $openinghours
 */
public function setOpeninghours($openinghours)
{
    $this->openinghours = $openinghours;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDocument()
{
    return $this->document;
}

/**
 * @param string $document
 */
public function setDocument($document)
{
    $this->document = $document;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getAddedts()
{
    return $this->addedts;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $addedts
 */
public function setAddedts($addedts)
{
    $this->addedts = $addedts;
}


/**
 * @return ArrayCollection | Store
 */
public function getGameHallOpeningHours()
{
    return $this->gameHallOpeningHours;
}

/**
 * @param array $gameHallOpeningHours
 */
public function setGameHallOpeningHours(array $gameHallOpeningHours)
{
    $this->gameHallOpeningHours = $gameHallOpeningHours;
}



}
```

> StoreTimings.php

```
namespace Test\BotBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * StoreTimings
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="store_timings")
 */
class StoreTimings
{ 
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
 private $id;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="store",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gameHallID", referencedColumnName="storeID")
 */
private $gameHallID;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="day", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
 */
private $day;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="opening_hours", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
 */
private $openingHours;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="closing_hours", type="string", length=11, nullable=true)
 */
private $closingHours;

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getGameHallID()
{
    return $this->gameHallID;
}

/**
 * @param int $gamehallid
 */
public function setGamehallid($gamehallid)
{
    $this->gameHallID = $gamehallid;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDay()
{
    return $this->day;
}

/**
 * @param string $day
 */
public function setDay($day)
{
    $this->day = $day;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getOpeningHours()
{
    return $this->openingHours;
}

/**
 * @param string $openingHours
 */
public function setOpeningHours($openingHours)
{
    $this->openingHours = $openingHours;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getClosingHours()
{
    return $this->closingHours;
}

/**
 * @param string $closingHours
 */
public function setClosingHours($closingHours)
{
    $this->closingHours = $closingHours;
}

}
```

i am able to generate the forms containing fields from both the entities but while saving i am getting Integrity Constriant Violation.

I have done too much of SO / googled a lot. Also i am newbie to Symfony.

> Also when i try to print before saving to the DB i get below object

```
Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store Object
(
[storeID:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 
[name:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => ergeg
[address:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => Rege
[zip:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => rger
[city:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => erg
[province:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => gerg
[phone:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => rg
[reference:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 
[email:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 
[coords:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 
[loungepage:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 1
[hasvouchers:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 1
[cashoutallowed:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 1
[hasparking:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 1
[hashotkeys:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 1
[openinghours:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 
[document:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 
[gameHallOpeningHours:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings Object
            (
                [id:Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings:private] => 
                [gameHallID:Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings:private] 
=> 
                [day:Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings:private] => 1
                [openingHours:Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings:private] => 
                [closingHours:Test\BotBundle\Entity\StoreTimings:private] => 
            )

    )

    [addedts:Test\BotBundle\Entity\Store:private] => 
)
```

> StoreType.php

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('address')
        ->add('zip')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('province')
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('loungepage')
        ->add('hasvouchers')
        ->add('cashoutallowed')
        ->add('hasparking')
        ->add('hashotkeys')
    ;

       $builder->add('store_id','collection',[
            'type' => 'store_timings',
            'property_path' => 'game_hall_opening_hours',
            'allow_add'    => true,
        ]); 


}
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Store::class,
    ));
}
```

> StoreTimingsType.php

```
class StoreTimingsType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('day','choice',[
            'choices' => [
                1=>'Monday',
                2=>'Tuesday',
                3=>'Wednesday',
                4=>'Thursday',
                5=>'Friday',
                6=>'Saturday',
                7=>'Sunday'],
        ])
        ->add('opening_hours')
        ->add('closingHours');

}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => StoreTimings::class,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself where StoreTimings::setGameHallID() is being called and the solution will be obvious.

Comment: @Cerad storeID maps to GameHallID and storeID is an auto increment field.

Comment: So?  Read my comment.  There are actually several hundred identical questions.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form you need to add a setter for `gameHallID` that is a relation like this inside your formBuilder

```
->add('brand', EntityType::class, array(
        // query choices from this entity
        'class' => 'YourBundle:YourClass',
    ))
```

or you can make `nullable=true` inside the field like this:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="gameHallID", referencedColumnName="storeID", nullable=true)
```

Comment: Cant make it nullable as its a foreign key and i need to map the gamehallid to the storeid

Comment: so you need to add into your form the value

Comment: and how do i do that ? Do you want me to paste the form in here ?

Comment: update answer, I advise you to read the documentatiuon about form builder and relation of symfony

Answer (score 0):

May be i couldn't explain the question properly.
But i somehow with experimentation found that below solution worked:

```
/**
* @param array $gameHallOpeningHours 
*/
public function setGameHallOpeningHours(array $gameHallOpeningHours)
{
  foreach($gameHallOpeningHours as $timeSlots){
   $timeSlots->setGameHall($this);
   }
   $this->gameHallOpeningHours = $gameHallOpeningHours;
 }
```

** GameHall is a private variable in the StoreTimings.php